# Change default behavior of Fn+Funtion key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, brightness

I have the latest version of Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my Toshiba Satellite C55D-B5212.

All of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key combinations work correctly except the brightness down and brightness up ones (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>).  I installed the brightness indicator from https://launchpad.net/~indicator-brightness/+archive/ubuntu/ppa and added custom keyboard shortcuts to change the brightness.

However, when I entered <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> into the keyboard settings dialog, it came up as "Battery" and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> came up as "Sleep".  Pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> puts the laptop to sleep and pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> has no obvious effect.

Is there any way to get these key combinations to work the way I want?

Answer (score 4):

I have exactly the same laptop and i had the same problem.

You must change the video card drivers. Go to Additional Drivers and select the option: **"Using video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx (proprietary)"** and reboot the system

Then you have to program the keys. First install xdotool:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Then open Keyboard from System Settings (Applications->System Tools->System Settings in Gnome).

Go to the Shortcut tab add press "+" to add the following shortcut:

```
Name: Brightness Up
Command: xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessUp
```

Click "Apply" then click on "Disabled" next to the new "Brightness Up" entry. Now press the key that corresponds to brightness up - F3 for me, but possibly F7 or something else for you.

Click "+" again and repeat the above steps to add the following entry for brightness down:

```
Name: Brightness Down
Command: xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessDown
```