# Change screen brightness increment

Tags: brightness, backlight

I am on a stock Ubuntu 20.04 LTS machine with gnome. Using the brightness controls on my keyboard ('fn' + left/right arrow keys), I can adjust the screen brightness up or down (this brings up a gnome-styled slider and sun-like brightness icon, showing where I am in the range between lowest and highest brightness).

Going by the values in `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`, the brightness varies between `1200` and `120000`, in increments of `5940`.

I can set the brightness to other values by redirecting to the `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` file (*). To my surprise, the modification persists even through keypresses to change the brightness (i.e. setting it to `3600` and then pressing 'fn' + right arrow once yields a brightness of `9540` (= 3600 + 5940) (**).

However, what I really want is more fine-grained control. I'd ideally like to change the existing `5940` to something more like `2000`.

I did try `grep -r 5940 /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/*` in the hope that the value might simply have been stored as a writeable setting somewhere, but no such luck. Apart from that, I'm at a loss as to where to look. I could swear that the values (both the minimum and the increment) were different back in 18.04 (on the same physical machine).

(*) For some reason,

```
drubbels@drubbels:~$ sudo echo 3600 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

fails, but

```
drubbels@drubbels:~$ su
Password:
root@drubbels:/home/drubbels# echo 3600 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

does work.

(**) It does get 'squashed down' back to the existing minimum or maximum of `1200` or `120000` when I try to take it below or above those.

Note: I do not believe this is a duplicate question. I did find a number of other similar questions complete with answers, but most of these were from 2012 and referenced settings & menus which no longer seem to exist

Comment: Your min and max values are stored in the same directory. I imagine max - min / 5940 is the number of steps your application is coded for. It's simple to write a script that adjusts at 1% steps.

Comment: My max brightness (120000) is indeed stored there, but my min brightness isn't. Also, the max_brightness file is not writeable (I get Permission Denied *even* when working as root).

Comment: You never write to max or min. You just write to brightness a value between min and max.

Comment: Just checking if you have found a solution?

Comment: No, I have not. I could write my own script - and even tie it to some hotkey combination - to modify the brightness value, but I do not know how to connect it to the existing brightness keys. This is because the existing brightness key combo is [fn + left/right arrow], and the function key is uniquely not directly accessible as a key press event. The recognition of [fn + arrow key] happens somewhere before the OS (maybe in the BIOS?). The OS is of course informed _somehow_ (it has to adjust the brightness), but it doesn't happen as the kind of normal key event which I would know how to access.

Comment: This might help a bit: https://askubuntu.com/questions/575952/change-default-behavior-of-fnfuntion-key